# Using setTimeout with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

I am trying to put a timer on an open case.  I put this on my button

```
 <input type="submit" value="Checkout" name="submitAction" class="btn btn-block alert-success" onclick="unlockcase()" />
```

Here is my function that calls my controller and closes the case after 15 minutes.

```
      function unlockcase() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var id = @Model.ID
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/Case/UnlockCase',
         data: 'id=' + id,
         success: function () {
             window.location.reload(true);

         }
     });
        },15000);
   };
```

It hits the function and the controller but it happens immediately without the timer working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the 15 minute wait defined?

Comment: The timer has `100` as input, which is 100 millisec.

Comment: put 15 * 60 * 1000 in place of 100.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should of changed that.  I lowered it earlier to make sure it was hitting my controller.  I'll edit it

Comment: 15000 means 15 seconds not 15 minutes. the unit is millisecond here.

Comment: By *it happens immediately* do you mean page reloads immediately? It is because of `type="submit"` remove that, and the ajax would work fine.

Comment: You do not cancel the click...

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your `html` to this

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-block alert-success" onclick="unlockcase()">Checkout</button>
```

Then your `javascript` can be as followes

```
    function unlockcase() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var id = @Model.ID;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Case/UnlockCase',
                data: 'id=' + id,
                success: function () {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
             });
         }, 15 * 1000 * 60);
     }
```

The unit of waiting period in `setTimeoout` is `millisecond` so `15 * 1000` means 15 seconds and `15 * 1000 * 60` means 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery why not use the `.click()` event on the button. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Checkout" name="submitAction" class="btn btn-block alert-success myButton" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    var counter = 1;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(counter > 900000){ //If it passed 15 minutes.
            //DO YOUR AJAX CALL
            var id = @Model.ID;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Case/UnlockCase',
                data: 'id=' + id,
                success: function () {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
             });
            //Clear the loop
            clearInterval(timer); 
        }
        counter++;
    }, 1000);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoggen1o/